# How can I reduce the logarithmic cost of this function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

At the work we are now trying to improve the performance of the code. So, to do that, we want to avoid the logarithm cost of the functions.

If you have a loop inside of a loop it has a higher cost, than if you can solve the problem with first a loop and then an other loop. Check the wikipedia link about this. [Analysis of Algorithms](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/41analysis/)

Okey, and the problem that I have is this array of objects with arrays.

```
const arr = [{
    value1: [true, true],
    value2: [true, true],
 }, {
    value3: [true, true], 
    value4: [true, false],
 }
]
```

I want to know if any of the inside values are false. In this example the last one is false, so the function hasError, is gonna show me **true**. If we change the value4 from the second object to true, it will return **false**.

This is my approach with a higher cost:

```
function hasError (a) {
    return a.some(obj=> {
        return Object.values(obj).some(arr => {
            return arr.some(boolean => {
                return boolean === false 
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Any cheaper solution?

Comment: I don't think you quite understand time complexity analysis. Your current implementation is not logarithmic, it's linear (with respect to total array items). Nor is unwrapping the for loops going to change time complexity, it'll remain linear.

Comment: you are iterating once. just because there are loops doesn't mean you are re iterating on any single item more than once

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interface for your array object that keeps track of the number of false values. `insert` and `update` methods will increment or decrement the counter (of `false` values). The `hasError` method would then just have to ask if the number of `false` values is greater than 0.

Of course this solution includes some overhead, but it makes the `hasError` method have O(1) time.

Comment: can you put an example?

Answer (score 0):

If the values will *always* be true or false, then you can make a `Set` out of the items and use `size` to check if there are two values:

```
function hasError(a) {
  return new Set(a.flatMap(Object.values).flat()).size == 2;
}
```